# How to back up user data from recovery mode?

Tags: backup, recovery-mode, boot-loop, data-recovery

My micromax canvas nitro A311 is stuck in boot loop.I have tried to solve the boot loop problem but couldn't succeed.The only solution seems to me is to format my phone.I am able to go to the recovery mode.It shows the following options:-

1. reboot system now
2. apply update from ADB
3. apply update from sdcard
4. apply update from cache
5. wipe data/factory reset
6. wipe cache partition
7. backup user data
8. restore user data

When i select the "backup user data" option ,it shows "SD card  did not have enough free space".It is reading my internal sdcard but not the external one.Is there any way I can back up data on an external sdcard or on my PC?My android phone is rooted.

Answer (score 1):

With the option for update via ADB, you can likely use ADB commands while the phone is in recovery and connected to a computer.

1. First, you will need the ADB files: [found here](http://www.mediafire.com/download/6b3aw3dq8omefyw/mfastboot-v2.zip)
2. Unzip the contents to the computer. I recommend root of drive i.e. `C:\adb`
3. Next, you will need USB drivers to connect the phone to the computer and be able to execute commands: [found here](http://gsmusbdriver.com/micromax-a311)
4. Install drivers via usual Windows methods
5. Go to the folder where you extracted ADB files
6. Hold the Left Shift key and right-click mouse
7. Select "Open command window here"
8. Connect the phone to the computer and boot to recovery. Test connect:

   ```
   adb devices
   ```
9. You should get the output for the server starting and a line showing the phone's serial number if the connection is possible
10. Providing all is well:

    ```
    adb pull /sdcard/.
    ```

    This should pull all contents on the internal SD card to the current directory

    This will NOT retrieve data stored elsewhere such as phone logs or text messages or contacts.  Unfortunately, those will be lost without the option to recover from the boot loop. It will only recover data saved on the data partition in phones, such as photos, music, and other misc info saved by apps.
11. Try wipe cache partition to see if that gets past boot loop. The only option I can think of. Or simply flash a custom recovery like TWRP that allows access to an external SD card: https://forum.xda-developers.com/a310/orig-development/twrp-recovery-micromax-canvas-nitro-a311-t3066387

Comment: Update from ADB only is usable with the `adb sideload` and `adb devices` commands in stock recovery, other ADB commands are not supported. The adb service in stock recovery is very limited and you cannot access user data or other 'normal' functions of adb on a fully functioning device.

Comment: His device is rooted.. said so himself.  I've connected and ran adb commands on android devices in recovery so read before you down vote something.

Comment: Not stock recovery... TWRP, CWM, or PhilZ perhaps, but not stock recovery. OP's menu clearly is stock recovery. And don't assume I am the one who down-voted your answer just because I commented.

Comment: symantics.  I could have phrased it differently in my answer.  I don't contest stock recovery; or its limitations.  but not every android device is developed the same.  I had a non-branded alcatel that allowed commands in stock recovery without root.  And I did suggest loading custom recovery in my answer and provided link.

Comment: When I start my S6 in recovery mode "adb devices" returns always empty. I can see the device only if I enter to Apply Update from ADB, is that normal? should we enter there first?

Answer (score 0):

You can backup and restore with TWRP via:

```
adb backup --twrp

adb restore --twrp
```

Source: https://nerdschalk.com/twrp-backup-pc-adb/